# ASN.1 hexdump of PDU

Tags: asn.1, hexdump

Am learning on to understand ASN.1 [Rectangle encode](https://lionet.info/asn1c/asn1c-usage.html#SECTION02310000000000000000) program.

Currently the program given on the website is printing in XML format and generated ber file. I wanted to print/read the PDU in hex encoded format (hexdump). Initially, I tried opening the test.ber file using an editor. But not opening properly.

I found uper_encoder does the job, and it's parameters are same as ber_encode same parameters. The compilation is also success `cc -g -I. -o rencode.x *.c` but on executing. Program fails with error `Couldn't encode rectangle` at function uper_encode as it returns -1.

`ec = uper_encode (&asn_DEF_Rectangle, rectangle, write_out, fp)`

Could I get some help in printing them in hex format.

Answer (score 1):

@Gopi,

With the caveat I have no experience with Lev Walkin's ASN.1 compiler, there are a couple of issues you're probably having:

1. Hex dumping means *decoding*, not encoding, but you are trying to use `uper_encode` instead.
2. The `test.ber` file is BER-encoded, but you are using a PER function to try to dump it out.

I can't help you with using the code, but you need to use something like `ber_decode` (or whatever the equivalent is) to decode the data; then you can create a hex dump from the decoded bytes.